# Find IP on a page with regex using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to find IPs located on a website with jQuery. Page looks like:

```
<a href='ipcheck.php?ip=127.0.0.1'>127.0.0.1</a>
```

How do I find that 127.0.0.1 using a regex? The text one, not the href attribute one. If you could do an example (where it alerts it), I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I used this to find my IP and add a class:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/);
}).addClass('ips');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to scan nodes to detect if they have IP addresses in them, you could use something like...

```
$("body").text().match(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/g);
```

That should return a list of all things that look like IP addresses. You could drop ones which couldn't be an IPv4 address with...

```
ips = ips.filter(function(ip) { 
                 return ip.split(".").every(function(octet, index) { 
                                              return octet <= 255 && octet >= 0; 
                                            });
                 });
```

If you wanted the best browser support, swap `filter()` and `every()` with `$.grep()` and adjust accordingly.

Note that this will allow `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`. You may want a subset of these to be valid, so adjust accordingly.

If you don't have jQuery, you could just use regular JavaScript...

```
var ips = (function me(node) {   
    return [].reduce.call(node.childNodes, function (ips, node) {
            return ips.concat(({
            1: me,
            3: function (node) {
                return node.data.match(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/g);
            }
        })[node.nodeType](node) || []);
    }, []);
})(document.body);
```

This basically walks every node that's a descendent of `body`, matching IP addresses and adding them to an array.

Comment: Perfect. Works perfectly! Thank you. Will accept for answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: You might be able to tell me how to add a class to the found text? .addClass()

Comment: @Snorlax To do that, you'd need a reference to the parent element of the text node. You could get a list of all text nodes it appears in, and then select their parent element and add the class to that.

Comment: Class added. Thank you once again. Check OP if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following,

```
$("body a").text().match(/^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/g);
```

Comment: That's one big regex. If you use this, leave a comment that this is for validating an IP.

Comment: @alex: we can use above regex for validating an IP also.

Comment: I meant a comment in the source code so future readers can know what it is the code is trying to do without needing to mentally parse the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get ip if it is a valid one by using this regex:

```
((?:(?:0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|0?\d{1,2}))
```

Example:

```
$("body").text().match(/((?:(?:0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|0?\d{1,2}))/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using http://jsfiddle.net/UJtut/:

```
$('a').each(function (i, el) {
  if(/\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b/.test(el.innerHTML)) {
    alert(el.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

Regex taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score -2):

Eddited to extract from multiple anchor with the same url with Jquery [check it](http://jsfiddle.net/VZfut/18/)

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href').split("?")[0] === "ipcheck.php")
        alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: I eddited the link, it was broken :)

Comment: What? It has no id called "link".